# make the first letter in a string uppercase and give a space before the first capital character in a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have an array with predefined objects

```
let columns=[
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "filter": false,
        "checkboxSelection": true,
        "width": 30
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 90,
        "suppressMenuHide": true,
        "cellStyle": {
            "white-space": "pre-wrap"
        },
        "rowHeight": 150
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "suppressMenuHide": true,
        "filterParams": {},
        "width": 130
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 130,
        "suppressMenuHide": false
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 130
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "minWidth": 80
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 130
    }
]
```

my  source array 'dataSet' has keys which needs to be made as the value property in the column array

```
let dataSet=[
    {
        "sector": "Bengaluru (BLR)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "08945",
        "ruleType": "Data rule",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 3
    },
    {
        "sector": "Abu dhabi (AUH)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "48646",
        "ruleType": "Rule set",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 3
    },
    {
        "sector": "Mumbai (BOM)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "65235",
        "ruleType": "Quality rule",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 3
    },
    {
        "sector": "Phuket (PKT)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "70946",
        "ruleType": "Data rule",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 4
    },
    {
        "sector": "Muscat (MCT)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "37546",
        "ruleType": "Rule set",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 13
    },
    {
        "sector": "Abu dhabi (AUH)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "48646",
        "ruleType": "Rule set",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 3
    },
    {
        "sector": "Mumbai (BOM)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "65235",
        "ruleType": "Quality rule",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 3
    },
    {
        "sector": "Mumbai (BOM)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "65235",
        "ruleType": "Quality rule",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 3
    },
    {
        "sector": "Phuket (PKT)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "70946",
        "ruleType": "Data rule",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 4
    },
    {
        "sector": "Muscat (MCT)",
        "sales": "high",
        "flightNumber": "37546",
        "ruleType": "Rule set",
        "failedRow": 70,
        "delta": 13
    }
]
```

my aim is to replace the columns array keys 'field' and 'headerName' with the corresponding keys of the dataset array objects,
ie,
my columns array values for the object key should be the keys in the objects of the  dataset array
my columns array after the operation should look like this,

```
let columns=[
        {
            "field": "",
            "headerName": "",
            "filter": false,
            "checkboxSelection": true,
            "width": 30
        },
        {
            "field": "sector",
            "headerName": "Sector",
            "width": 90,
            "suppressMenuHide": true,
            "cellStyle": {
                "white-space": "pre-wrap"
            },
            "rowHeight": 150
        },
        {
            "field": "sales",
            "headerName": "Sales"
            "suppressMenuHide": true,
            "filterParams": {},
            "width": 130
        },
        {
            "field": "flightNumber",
            "headerName": "Flight Number"
            "width": 130,
            "suppressMenuHide": false
        },
        {
            "field": "ruleType",
            "headerName": "Rule Type",
            "width": 130
        },
        {
            "field": "failedRow",
            "headerName": "Failed Row",
            "minWidth": 80
        },
        {
            "field": "delta",
            "headerName": "Delta",
            "width": 130
        }
    ]
```

is there a work around to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```js
let columns=[
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "filter": false,
        "checkboxSelection": true,
        "width": 30
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 90,
        "suppressMenuHide": true,
        "cellStyle": {
            "white-space": "pre-wrap"
        },
        "rowHeight": 150
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "suppressMenuHide": true,
        "filterParams": {},
        "width": 130
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 130,
        "suppressMenuHide": false
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 130
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "minWidth": 80
    },
    {
        "field": "",
        "headerName": "",
        "width": 130
    }
]


const e = {
  "sector": "Mumbai (BOM)",
  "sales": "high",
  "flightNumber": "65235",
  "ruleType": "Quality rule",
  "failedRow": 70,
  "delta": 3
}

const unCamelCase = (s) => s[0].toUpperCase() + s.substring(1).replace(/([A-Z])/g, r => ` ${r}`)

const res = columns.map( (c,i) => i===0 ? c : (i = Object.keys(e)[i-1], {...c, field: i, headerName:unCamelCase(i)}))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Basically just taking the keys of the object and create column data for it by putting them into the `field` and `headerName` props of the provided array.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this requirement by just getting the first object keys from `dataSet` array and then iterate the `columns` array and bind the keys to the properties.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let dataSet=[
  {
    "sector": "Bengaluru (BLR)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "08945",
    "ruleType": "Data rule",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 3
  },
  {
    "sector": "Abu dhabi (AUH)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "48646",
    "ruleType": "Rule set",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 3
  },
  {
    "sector": "Mumbai (BOM)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "65235",
    "ruleType": "Quality rule",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 3
  },
  {
    "sector": "Phuket (PKT)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "70946",
    "ruleType": "Data rule",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 4
  },
  {
    "sector": "Muscat (MCT)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "37546",
    "ruleType": "Rule set",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 13
  },
  {
    "sector": "Abu dhabi (AUH)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "48646",
    "ruleType": "Rule set",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 3
  },
  {
    "sector": "Mumbai (BOM)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "65235",
    "ruleType": "Quality rule",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 3
  },
  {
    "sector": "Mumbai (BOM)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "65235",
    "ruleType": "Quality rule",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 3
  },
  {
    "sector": "Phuket (PKT)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "70946",
    "ruleType": "Data rule",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 4
  },
  {
    "sector": "Muscat (MCT)",
    "sales": "high",
    "flightNumber": "37546",
    "ruleType": "Rule set",
    "failedRow": 70,
    "delta": 13
  }
];

let columns=[
  {
    "field": "",
    "headerName": "",
    "filter": false,
    "checkboxSelection": true,
    "width": 30
  },
  {
    "field": "",
    "headerName": "",
    "width": 90,
    "suppressMenuHide": true,
    "cellStyle": {
      "white-space": "pre-wrap"
    },
    "rowHeight": 150
  },
  {
    "field": "",
    "headerName": "",
    "suppressMenuHide": true,
    "filterParams": {},
    "width": 130
  },
  {
    "field": "",
    "headerName": "",
    "width": 130,
    "suppressMenuHide": false
  },
  {
    "field": "",
    "headerName": "",
    "width": 130
  },
  {
    "field": "",
    "headerName": "",
    "minWidth": 80
  },
  {
    "field": "",
    "headerName": "",
    "width": 130
  }
];

const columnKeys = Object.keys(dataSet[0]);

columns.forEach((column, index) => {
  const key = columnKeys[index - 1]
  if (!column.checkboxSelection) {
    column.field = key
    column.headerName = (key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1)).split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ")
  }
});

console.log(columns);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar answer to @Rohít but wasn't quick enough. I like his because it didn't require lodash. :P

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const fixedTitle = [["",""],...Object.keys(dataSet[0]).map(k=>[k,_.startCase(k)])]

const result = columns.map((col,index)=>({
  ...col,
  field: fixedTitle[index][0],
  headerName: fixedTitle[index][1]
}))
```